# Passing data in PHP file to JS file in JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to build a small program on a webpage that shows a `drop-down` list input type with the makes of cars (`Ford` and `BMW` in this case). Once a selection is made, the user clicks the submit button and below the form, a list of models specific to the make will appear in the results `div`.

I was provided with 4 files:

**index.php:**

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="make">
            Make
            <select name="make" id="make">
                <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
                <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
                <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
            </select>
        </label>
  <input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**data.php:**

```
<? php

function data() {
  $data = array(
    array(
      'make' => 'Ford',
      'model' => 'Fiesta'
    ),
    array(
      'make' => 'Ford',
      'model' => 'Focus'
    ),
    array(
      'make' => 'Ford',
      'model' => 'Mustang'
    ),
    array(
      'make' => 'BMW',
      'model' => '320'
    ),
    array(
      'make' => 'BMW',
      'model' => 'X3'
    ),
    array(
      'make' => 'BMW',
      'model' => 'X5'
    ),
  );
}
```

**ajax.php:**

```
<?php
require_once( 'data.php' );
$data      = data();
$json_data = array();
```

**And main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  var run_ajax = function() {
    results = $('#results');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {

      },
      success: function(response) {

      },
    });
  }

  $('#submit').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    run_ajax();
  });

});
```

How do I access the data in `data.php` from `main.js`? I'd appreciate a thorough explanation of possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not you make the javascript array of data instead of in php

Comment: I'd have thought a general "how to Ajax with PHP and JavaScript" tutorial was out of scope for StackOverflow, but: update the PHP to actually return that array (echo). Then the `response` argument in the `$.ajax()` success callback will be an array of objects, so `response[0].make` is `"Ford"`, and `response[0].model` is `"Fiesta"`, etc. So use a loop to iterate over that array...

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you maybe show me an example in code? Sorry, I'm a total noob.

I need to keep in mind that only `response[ i ].model`s with `response[ i ].make` equal to `"Ford"` can be shown when the dropdown list choice of `"Ford"` is selected. Same with BMW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing is done seeing your provided code you have to just connect them but first you need to change the `data.php` file to the following

```
<?php
function data() {
return array(
    array(
        'make'  => 'Ford',
        'model' => 'Fiesta'
    ),
    array(
        'make'  => 'Ford',
        'model' => 'Focus'
    ),
    array(
        'make'  => 'Ford',
        'model' => 'Mustang'
    ),
    array(
        'make'  => 'BMW',
        'model' => '320'
    ),
    array(
        'make'  => 'BMW',
        'model' => 'X3'
    ),
    array(
        'make'  => 'BMW',
        'model' => 'X5'
    ),
);}
```

then your `ajax.php` file to the following

```
  <?php
   require_once( 'data.php' );
   $data      = data();
    $make   =   $_POST['make'];

    // print_r($data);exit;
foreach($data as $car){
    if(in_array($make,$car)){
        $filtered[]=$car;
    }
}
 echo json_encode($filtered);
```

then change your `main.js` function to the following

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    var run_ajax = function () {
        results = $('#results');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (response) {
                for (var key in
                        response) {
                    $("#results").append(" <div > Make: " + response[key]['make'] +
                        ", Model:" + response[key]['model'] + " </div>");
                }
            },
        });
    }
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        run_ajax();
    });
});
```

hope that sorts out

**EDIT**

Actually, we have to send the select dropdown's selected make and filter out the cars with the same make to be responsed back and shown in the lower div have to change a few more things inside the ajax.php file

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting an error in my JS though, specifically this line: `forEach(var key in response){`

The console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

Comment: sorry it was a typo it should be `for` instead of `forEach` i updated the code

Comment: Thank you. I updated it and I'm getting a new error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined" in reference to the line `data: formData`

Comment: hmm looks like we are not sending anything and `formData` is obviously undefined let me update the answer

Comment: no @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez he actually has to send the data and show only those models that match with the make that he slected inthe dropdown , i just updated the answer

Comment: I removed the comment. It´s ok @MuhammadOmerAslam.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Seems like that fixed the error! Although now when I press the submit button though it doesn't do anything. Also, when I try to `console.log(response);` within the success function, no data is displayed.

Comment: okay let me replicate it on mylocal machine will let you know in a moment

Comment: @thenomadicmann i just updated the answer you need to copy all the code again it will work for sure now

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Dude, thank you. You are brilliant!

I just needed to tweak the `url` target to `'ajax.php'`, I think you may have swapped that by mistake. Thank you again!

Comment: oops ! yeah that name `filter.php` was for the file on my local machine , glad i could help you out no problem , i will fix this in my answer tho

Answer (score 0):

Your `data()` function must first `return` an array:

```
function data(){
    $data = array('key'=>'value'); 
    return $data;
}
```

Then `echo` or `print()` the json_encoded array:

```
$data = data();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: that does not filter the cars with the same make that is posted to the php file  via ajax request , the OP wants to show the same make cars under the form

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your you dont need to define a function in your data.php file, since it is included in the ajax.php file, any variable there would be accessible

**data.php:**

```
<? php
$data = array(
  array(
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'Fiesta'
  ),
  array(
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'Focus'
  ),
  array(
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' => 'Mustang'
  ),
  array(
    'make' => 'BMW',
    'model' => '320'
  ),
  array(
    'make' => 'BMW',
    'model' => 'X3'
  ),
  array(
    'make' => 'BMW',
    'model' => 'X5'
  ),
);
```

the ajax.php file reads the data from data.php file filters the array and put the models of the selected make into a new array and echo as json string

**ajax.php:**

```
<?php
require_once('data.php');
$filtered_make = [];
$make = $_POST['make'];
foreach ($data as $car) {
  if (strtolower($make) == strtolower($car['make'])) $filtered_make[] = $car['model'];
}

echo json_encode($filtered_make);
```

**index.php:**

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="make">
    Make
    <select name="make" id="make">
      <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
<script src="http://www.izivote.com/res/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

onsuccess, in the main.js file, the returned list of models in the json object from ajax.php is put in a list and displayed in the result container

**main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(() => {

var run_ajax = function() {
results = $('#results');
var formData =  $('#form').serialize();

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'ajax.php',
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function() {

},
success: function(response) {
var resultHTML = "<ul>";
  for(var index in response){
  resultHTML += "<li>" + response[index] + "</li>";
  }
  resultHTML += "</ul>";
results.html(resultHTML);
},
});
}

$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

run_ajax();
});

});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

return the `data()` as an array.
then encode the `$data` to json.

```
<?php
require_once( 'data.php' );
$data      = data();
$json_data = json_encode(array());
```

and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function( response ) {
           console.log(response); // check the return result
           $.each(response, function(key, val){
              $("#results").append("<div>Make:"+key+" , Model:"+val+"</div>");
           });
        },
        error: function (msg) {
           alert("Error: check console");
           console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

not tested but hope it helps

Comment: you are not encoding anything to json in your php file this does not provide the solution that the OP requested , you line `$json_data = json_encode(array());` does nothing more over the `formData` would be throwing error too as it would be undefined